# Regex (JS): Match URLs without a protocal, ignore URLS that with one

Tags: javascript, regex

Apologies for yet another regex URL matching question, but I haven't been a able to find a solution in any of the other threads.

I want to run a `replace()` method on a string, with a pattern that matches all URLs without a protocal (http, https etc) but ignores urls that do have one.

So given this input:

`www.google.com www.facebook.com
http://www.google.com
http://www.facebook.com`

It would match `www.google.com` and `www.facebook.com` on the first line (without any surrounding whitespace), but ignore the other URLs on the second and third line.

I thought about just looking for `www` and ignoring matches which have `//` as preceding characters, which led me to this:

https://www.regex101.com/r/Y3rqxy/1

However, as you can see the second match includes the preceding whitespace. As I want to replace the `www` with `http://www` this whitespace buggers things up a little.

Any regex mandarins able to help me out on this one?

Comment: And you don't want to add `http://` if the url is `google.com` ? How about rather something like [`str.replace(/(^|\s)\b(?!http)/g, '$1http://');`](https://jsfiddle.net/z0pfx6tv/)

Answer (score 0):

Mere seconds after posting this, one of my colleagues came up with a solution. It's a little wacky (thanks javascript) but it works! This example assumes you want to add `http://` to any URLs that are missing their protocal.

First you have to reverse the string you're running the `.replace()` method on:

`string.split('').reverse().join('')`

Then you can run call the replace method with the following regex (note the backwards `http://www`!):

`string.replace(/www(?!\/\/)/gi, 'www//:ptth')`

Then you just reverse your string again:

`string.split('').reverse().join('')`

And any URLS that are missing a protocal in that string will now have them.

It's not going to win any awards for cleanliness, but it works!